# R - Create data frame based on the matched characters and lable them differently

Tags: r

I have a list of IDs and two of it's sub-groups. I am going to create a data.frame where the first column represents all IDs and the second column includes the matching values from each sub-groups which they labaled with a different symble. The first sub-group replaced by "TT" letters and the second by "NN" if they matched.

```
ID:
11EQ9
12BJ1
WRHK
12WSJ
WHWD

ID-1:
11EQ9
12BJ1
WRHK

ID-2:
12WSJ
WHWD
```

So, the expected result would be like this:

```
ID      Sym
11EQ9   TT
12BJ1   TT
WHWD    NN
WRHK    TT
12WSJ   NN
```

I am looking to make it in an appropriate way in R. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `base R`

```
df1$Sym <- NA
df1$Sym[df1$ID %in% df2$`ID-1`] <- "TT"
df1$Sym[df1$ID %in% df3$`ID-2`] <- "NN"
```